# How to use NSUserDefault with PickerView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsuserdefaults, uipickerview

I made some `Labels` that change using `PickerView`. But when I change the `Label` and if I run my app again, it doesn't save to selected one. So I have to use `NSUserDefault` but I don't know how to use it in right way.

This is my code:

```
var selectedFood = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var foodLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var labelTwo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var labelThree: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var foodPicker: UIPickerView!

var food = ["Bread", "Pizza", "Pasta", "Hot Dog", "Burger"]

@IBAction func submitLanguageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (selectedFood == 0) {
       foodLabel.text = "Bread"
       labelTwo.text = "Bread is a staple food prepared from a dough of flour and water..."
       labelThree.text = "Bread is one of the oldest prepared foods..." // I used random information just as sample         
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 1) {
       foodLabel.text = "Pizza"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Pizza"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Pizza"   // I used random information just as sample              
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 2) {
       foodLabel.text = "Pasta"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Pasta"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Pasta"    // I used random information just as sample                 
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 3) {
       foodLabel.text = "Hot Dog"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Hot Dog"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Hot Dog"  // I used random information just as sample                   
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 4) {
       foodLabel.text = "Burger"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Burger"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Burger" // I used random information just as sample         
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    foodPicker.delegate = self
    foodPicker.dataSource = self


    if (selectedFood == 0) {
       foodLabel.text = "Bread"
       labelTwo.text = "Bread is a staple food prepared from a dough of flour and water..."
       labelThree.text = "Bread is one of the oldest prepared foods..." // I used random information just as sample         
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 1) {
       foodLabel.text = "Pizza"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Pizza"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Pizza"   // I used random information just as sample              
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 2) {
       foodLabel.text = "Pasta"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Pasta"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Pasta"    // I used random information just as sample                 
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 3) {
       foodLabel.text = "Hot Dog"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Hot Dog"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Hot Dog"  // I used random information just as sample                   
    }
    else if (selectedFood == 4) {
       foodLabel.text = "Burger"
       labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Burger"
       labelThree.text = "A fact about Burger" // I used random information just as sample         
    }
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return food[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return food.count
}

public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    selectedFood = row
}

}
```

So when I choose **Pizza**, whenever I run my app I want to be it **Pizza**, if I select another one for example **Pasta**, I want to be that one **Pasta**.
Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WBMDDrugManagerErrorCodeSave the selection like so:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(row, forKey: "choosenFood")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    self.setLabelsForChoice(row)
}
```

Retrieve the chosen selection like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    if let previousSelection:Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("choosenFood") as? Int{
        self.setLabelsForChoice(previousSelection)
    }
}
```

Create a label update method similar to this:

```
func setLabelsForChoice(_choice:Int){
    switch _choice{
        case 0:
            foodLabel.text = "Bread"
            labelTwo.text = "Bread is a staple food prepared from a dough of flour and water..."
            labelThree.text = "Bread is one of the oldest prepared foods..."
            break
        case 1:
            foodLabel.text = "Pizza"
            labelTwo.text = "Here will be more informations about Pizza"
            labelThree.text = "A fact about Pizza"
            break
        default:

            break
    }




}
```

Comment: What part didn't work? Can you ask a specific question by posting more code?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is to save data into the system for after the user closes the app and opens it again. What I wrote is how to save it in didSelect row and how to retrieve what is saved in viewWillAppear. If all you are trying to do is change the label according to what was selected then change the line selectedFood = row with foodLabel.text = food[row]

Comment: If I helped please mark my answer as correct. You'll probably have to post another question with the code of how you get from one view controller to the next for that one.